# Postscribe Unterminated String Literal

Tags: javascript

Attempting to use postscribe.js to async load ads (http://krux.github.io/postscribe/)

However, even the example in the documentation:

```
 postscribe('#ad', '<script src=doubleclick_url_with_params></script>');
```

Throws the "Unterminated String Literal" error.  It seems anything other than script tag will work.  How do I get a script tag into a string?

Comment: What's in `doubleclick_url_with_params`? Give us the literal code. There's nothing wrong with that piece.

Comment: On mobile but I'm sure this is a dupe. Escape script tags `<\/script>`